# Definite Integrals And Partitions

Tags: calculus

Prove that if a function $f(x)$ which is Integrable on $[a, b]$ then for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a partition of $[a, b]$ such that for that partition $U-L<\epsilon$
$$$$ Now as $f(x)$ is Integrable let $\int_a^bf(x)dx=I$. Now for any given $\frac{\epsilon}{2}>0$ there exists a $\delta$ such that for any partition we can make the difference $U-I<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ by making the norm of the partition $||P||<\delta$
$$$$Similarily we can make the difference $L-I<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ by making the norm of the partition $||P||<\delta$. So we can make the difference $U-L<\epsilon$ that is as small as we want by choosing sufficiently small $\epsilon$, where $U$ and $L$ mean upper sum and lower sum of a particular partition.
$$$$ Is My Proof Correct?

Comment: "Now for any given $\frac{\epsilon}{2}>0$ there exists a $\delta$ such that for any partition we can make the difference $U-I<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ by making the norm of the partition $||P||<\delta$" I think this is the core of the proof, so I would elaborate more on why it is correct

Comment: Is the whole proof correct or not?

Comment: Your proof is incomplete in my opinion.

Comment: Can you plz explain why my proof is incorrect?

Comment: I did not say it was incorrect, I said it was incomplete. I also explained where, In my opinion, you should expand your explanation.